# Change values of a pair of javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm a begginer and I'm coding this to change values of a whole array. For instance, my aim is to change ºC to ºK. But this code doesn't seems to work. It gives an error message: "j is undefined".
What's wrong with this code?

```
//Original Arrays

var I_t1=new Array();
var V_t1=new Array();

//Arrays de la tabla 1
var K_t1=new Array();
var P_t1=new Array();

function kelvin() {
    var i;

    var j = new Array();
    var k = new Array();

    var k;
    var j=V_t1.lenght;   

    var k=I_t1.lenght; // La k será igual a la longitud del array T

    for(i=0;i<j.length;i++){   
        K_t1[i]= (V_t1[i] * 200);
    }

    for(i=0;i<k.length;i++){      
        P_t1[i]= (I_t1[i] * 400);
    }
}
```

Until here, the code. So my question is:

-How do I modify this funcion to archieve its aim?

Comment: Several things: Think about indentation - it's almost impossible to read without it. Secondly, you're redeclaring `k` in the `kelvin` function a total of 3 times and `j` two times - why? Thirdly, `I_t1.lenght` should be `I_t1.length`. Fourthly, you're setting `j` and `k` to a NUMBER, yet you're trying to call `.length` on them and a number doesn't have a length. Skip out the `.length` part in the `for` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned there is a problem in the `.length`. 
But I would recommend a different approach to solve this problem. Try and use higher order functions like "map" to make this work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

e.g. A function to change ºC to ºK would be something like:

```
function celciusToKelvin(celciusVal){
   return celciusVal + 274.15;
}
```

Now if you have an array of celcius values like `var celciusValues = [12,23,34,45];`, you can call the map function like:

```
var kelvinValues = celciusValues.map(celciusToKelvin);
```

Comment: Hum, thanks! I'm going to try this solution changing the approach I've been following since now.

Comment: Wait a moment, there is something odd here. I will answer my own question to show the results.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your spelling - it's `.length`, not `.lenght`!

Comment: Wow!! length... No more errors in the web browser console. Thanks a lot.  EDIT: But still, it doesn't make any change in the values...

Comment: I am really happy that helped you! If something is undefined always look for spelling first - you may have missed a letter or swapped some :)